# Accessing .csv data from views file

Tags: django, csv, chart.js

I have a small Django app, and I'm trying to access data from a CSV file (static/blog/dat.csv, the static folder is at the same level as the templates folder and views.py; and everything is inside my blog app) so I can use it to plot a graph on the browser using Chart.js. Aside from not being able to do that, the app is working fine.

I know I'm gonna need to pass some sort of context to the view function, but I don't know how I'd do that. Also, I have a couple of similar csv files, and using them as static files in my app seems simpler and easier than to add everything to a database to access them that way.

```py
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
import csv

def rtest(request):
    url = staticfiles_storage.url('blog/dat.csv')
    with open(url, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
            context += line
    return render(request, 'blog/r.html', context)
```

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('r-test/', views.rtest, name='blog-r-test'),
]
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
FileNotFoundError at /r-test/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/blog/dat.csv'
```

I'm sure this is not the only error.

I know that the way I'm using the `context` variable is wrong, but that's just to kind of show what I'm trying to do. If I could just print one cell from the csv, I would view this as a win. Please help, thank you!

------Edit1-------
After using `staticfiles_storage.path()` instead of `staticfiles_storage.url()`

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /r-test/

You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

------Edit2------
I'm now able to find my csv file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/riccl/Documents/richie/Python/nuclear/main/book/static/book'
```

But my context variable still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you share your `STATIC_ROOT` setting? It looks like it's misconfigured

Comment: I don't have a  `STATIC_ROOT` in my settings.py file, but I have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`staticfiles_storage.path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.path) to read the file. `staticfiles_storage.url()` will return the URL that a user will use to load the static file on your site

[`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#static-root) is where all static files will be stored after you run [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic), most of the time this is set to `<root of the project>/static/`. This is also where `staticfiles_storage.path()` will look for static files.

You will also need to set [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) so that your file(s) can be found by `collectstatic`. I usually have a folder located at `<root of the project>/<project name>/static/` which I add to `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: Thank you! You were right. But now I'm getting a new error. Would you happen to know how I can correctly configure `STATIC_ROOT`? I just edited my question, and I think the context variable is still wrong...if you have any comments that can point me in the right direction. Thank you again!

Comment: I got it!! I'm using the absolute path C:/User/..... with the STATIC_ROOT variable. I can now find my csv file...but I still have the context error...the error message won't help a lot because it kinda doesnt make sense...I need to re-do the whole view function. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: What error are you getting? If you share the whole stacktrace it could be useful. You can put it on pastebin if it's too long

Comment: I dont have any error messages to share because my code doesn't make any sense.  All I have is the rtest function in the question above....it was just a frustrated attempt. I'm trying to pass a dictionary as context to my view function so I can use it in the template.